# Voice assistant can't find what I asked for from wikipedia so it exits

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi there so I made a voice assistant that can bring me information from Wikipedia and it works fine but in cases where it can't find a result from Wikipedia because Wikipedia hasn't written about that person/thing I want it to find, it gives me an error and finishes the process, So yeah I was just wondering if anyone knows how to fix this issue since it annoys me when my script just exits and I'm in a game and I can't ask it anything, I also have some more if statements down there but I didn't show them because I believe they don't affect the Wikipedia one.

Here's the code I used:

```
import pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyaudio
import wikipedia
import datetime
import webbrowser as wb
import pywhatkit
import os
from requests import get


engine = pyttsx3.init()
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[0].id) #changing index changes voices but ony 0 and 1 are working here
engine.runAndWait()


def speak(audio):
    engine.say(audio)
    print(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()


def takeCommand():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening...")
        audio = r.listen(source)

    try:
        print("Recognizing...")
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-in')
        print(f"user said: {query}\n")

    except Exception as e:
        print("Sorry i didn't catch that...")
        return ""
    return query


def wish():
    hour = datetime.datetime.now().hour
    if hour >= 6 and hour < 12:
        speak("Good Morning Sir!")
    elif hour >= 12 and hour < 18:
        speak("Good after noon Sir!")
    elif hour >= 18 and hour < 24:
        speak("Good evening Sir!")
    else:
        speak("Good night sir")
    speak("I am jarvis your personal assistant")


def time():
    Time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%I:%M:%S")
    speak(Time)


def date():
    year = int(datetime.datetime.now().year)
    month = int(datetime.datetime.now().month)
    date = int(datetime.datetime.now().day)
    speak(date)
    speak(month)
    speak(year)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    wish()
    while True:

        query = takeCommand()

        if 'according to wikipedia' in query.lower():
            speak('Searching wikipedia...')
            query = query.replace("wikipedia", "")
            results = wikipedia.summary(query, sentences=2)
            speak(results)
```

And the error im getting is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Yousif/PycharmProjects/Jarvis Mk2/main.py", line 78, in <module>
    results = wikipedia.summary(query, sentences=2)
  File "C:\Users\Yousif\PycharmProjects\Jarvis Mk2\venv\lib\site-packages\wikipedia\util.py", line 28, in __call__
    ret = self._cache[key] = self.fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Yousif\PycharmProjects\Jarvis Mk2\venv\lib\site-packages\wikipedia\wikipedia.py", line 231, in summary
    page_info = page(title, auto_suggest=auto_suggest, redirect=redirect)
  File "C:\Users\Yousif\PycharmProjects\Jarvis Mk2\venv\lib\site-packages\wikipedia\wikipedia.py", line 276, in page
    return WikipediaPage(title, redirect=redirect, preload=preload)
  File "C:\Users\Yousif\PycharmProjects\Jarvis Mk2\venv\lib\site-packages\wikipedia\wikipedia.py", line 299, in __init__
    self.__load(redirect=redirect, preload=preload)
  File "C:\Users\Yousif\PycharmProjects\Jarvis Mk2\venv\lib\site-packages\wikipedia\wikipedia.py", line 345, in __load
    raise PageError(self.title)
wikipedia.exceptions.PageError: Page id "who is tony stars according to wikipedia" does not match any pages. Try another id!
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question and mention the traceback there

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap that code with a try-except block like so:

```
def speak(audio):
    engine.say(audio)
    print(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()


def takeCommand():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening...")
        audio = r.listen(source)

    try:
        print("Recognizing...")
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-in')
        print(f"user said: {query}\n")

    except Exception as e:
        print("Sorry i didn't catch that...")
        return ""
    return query


def wish():
    hour = datetime.datetime.now().hour
    if hour >= 6 and hour < 12:
        speak("Good Morning Sir!")
    elif hour >= 12 and hour < 18:
        speak("Good after noon Sir!")
    elif hour >= 18 and hour < 24:
        speak("Good evening Sir!")
    else:
        speak("Good night sir")
    speak("I am jarvis your personal assistant")


def time():
    Time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%I:%M:%S")
    speak(Time)


def date():
    year = int(datetime.datetime.now().year)
    month = int(datetime.datetime.now().month)
    date = int(datetime.datetime.now().day)
    speak(date)
    speak(month)
    speak(year)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    wish()
    while True:

        query = takeCommand()

        if 'according to wikipedia' in query.lower():
            speak('Searching wikipedia...')
            query = query.replace("wikipedia", "")
            try:
                results = wikipedia.summary(query, sentences=2)
                speak(results)
            except wikipedia.exceptions.PageError:
                pass
```

Comment: Hey thank you for the response sorry I'm really new to programming I didn't understand where to put the code you talked about.

Comment: I edited the answer with the complete code.

Comment: Yeah I figured it out thank you alot I really appreciate it this issue was really annoying!